# Spring autowiring issue in spring batch

Tags: java, spring

I seem to be having an issue with the way I have implemented autowiring in my Spring Batch application.For example if I use:

```
public class A{

@Autowired
BeanList beanList;
}
```

this works fine for Class A.In the sense that,beanList returns the values that it should.But if from a method from class A I am calling a method from a different class and then have the same

```
@Autowired
BeanList beanList
```

,beanList return a null.But autowiring seems to work fine across steps.I have

Comment: so you are trying to autowire variable inside a method as local variable?

Comment: Yeah.I did not specify anything in particular - private or public

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. I assume, you have something like this:

```
public class A{

    B aB;

    @Autowired
    BeanList beanList;

    public void callToB() { aB.aMethod(); }
}

public class B {
    @Autowired
    BeanList beanList;

    public void aMethod() {Assert.notNull(beanList);}
}
```

If this is correct, then the problem is likely that you didn't instantiate class B as a "spring bean".

The most simply way to do this would be to mark class B with `@Component` and to autowire it into class A.

```
public class A {

    @Autowired
    B aB;
```

or to instantiate it with an `@Bean` directly in class A

```
@Component
public class A {

    @Autowired
    BeanList beanList;

    @Bean
    B myBean() {return new B();}

    public void callToB() { myBean().aMethod(); }
```

Does this describe and solve your problem?

Comment: Awesome @Hansjoerg.I autowired the class being called in the parent class and it worked.Looks like the issue as you pointed out was that the class being called was not registered as a spring bean.So I guess I need to either autowire it or explicilty add a bean element in the spring context xml file.